# How to use with plot_grid from cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, cowplot

I want to combine several ggplot2 charts into one using `cowplot::plot_grid()`. From its documentation:

```
?plot
Arguments

... 
List of plots to be arranged into the grid. The plots can be objects of one of the following classes: ggplot, recordedplot, gtable, or alternative can be a function creating a plot when called (see examples).
```

So, If I input a list of ggplot2 objects to `plot_grid()`, it should combine those plots into one, right?

So why won't this work?

```
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) 
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=70, vjust=0.5))

list(p1, p2) %>% 
  map(plot_grid)
```

Comment: Why not call plot_grid(p1, p2)?

Comment: @Blaza because I might have several plots to include in  plot_grid()

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation of `map` (`?map`), it states that:

```
.x     A list or atomic vector. 
.f     A function, formula, or atomic vector.
```

It means the function you provided for `.f` will be applied to every elements in `.x`. So the following code

```
list(p1, p2) %>% map(plot_grid)
```

is the same as the following code

```
plot_grid(p1)
plot_grid(p2)
```

,which is probably not what you want.

What you want is probably this

```
plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

Or this

```
plot_grid(plotlist = list(p1, p2))
```

Answer (score -1):

You want `do.call()`, not `map()`, to pass a list of arguments to a function. For your example above:

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) 
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=70, vjust=0.5))

plots <- list(p1, p2)
do.call(cowplot::plot_grid, plots)
```

Comment: `map` can also be used for passing argument as a list